# How to turn expression into method in Java language

Tags: java

For instance :

```
int x = 4;
int y = 5;
int z = (x * y);
```

Now I want to turn `(x * y)` into a function, I founded that **Dijkstra's Two-Stack** can help; But the problem is, a single expression will be used for many times, every time computing the expression, the system will instantiate two stack and use loop structure, hence it is inefficient. So is there a better way to deal with this problem?

Comment: Uh.. the expression is defined by user, e.g. it may be **(x * y) + z** or something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java includes [`ScriptEngine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html) (see also [Oracle Nashorn](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-nashorn-2126515.html)). You could use the `ScriptEngine` mechanism to embed [python](http://www.jython.org/), [ruby](http://jruby.org/), [scheme](http://sisc-scheme.org/), etc. But JavaScript is builtin so we can do,

```
ScriptEngineManager engineManager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = engineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");
try {
  engine.eval("function multiply(x, y) { return x * y; }");
  System.out.println(engine.eval("multiply(3, 2);"));
} catch (ScriptException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And get (as output)

```
6
```

Comment: Thanks ! The answer helps a lot.  It seems that nashorn engine is not available util Java 8, so rhino can be a replacement.

Comment: @Collin You can also just use `"javascript"`.